# Fix XSS vulnerability

Tags: asp.net, xss

Bellow code is vulnerable to XSS attacks. I verified that. I wanted to fix it. How can I do it? The code is written in classic asp.

```
Dim strGo : strGo = Request.QueryString.Item("go");

Response.Write "document.location.href = 'browserCompatibilities.asp?go=" & strGo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`encode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525347(v=vs.90)) the query string parameters:

```
Response.Write "document.location.href = 'browserCompatibilities.asp?go=" & 
 Server.HTMLEncode(strGo)
```